# jquery code execution issue in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function refreshdata() {
  $('.overlayloading').toggle(true);
  fetchData();
}
```

Here `$('.overlayloading').toggle(true)` is executing only after the execution of `fetchData()` in chrome. Its working fine in Mozilla. But it's not working in google chrome browser. I am trying to load loading animation before the `fetchData` function.But loading animation is showing after the execution of `fecthData` function.

Comment: any errors in the developer's console? With that amount of code you just provided is difficult to provide an answer to help you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$('.overlayloading').toggle(true)` executes before `fetchData()`, JS in Chrome would be fundamentally broken otherwise. However, it's very possible that `fetchData()` runs before the view is rerendered after the display has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback to toggle, so it actually waits for the animation to be finished before executing the function.

```
$('.overlayloading').toggle(400,fetchData);
```

If you want data to be loaded before the animation begins, you could pass the toggle function as callback to your fetchdata or return a promise, which you will use to execute the toggle within `then()`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is making asynchronous animations, javaScript runs on the browser's UI thread, if it was synchronous then the UI would freeze until the animation finishes.

What You can do is use the `callback` method of `.toggle`, it will run after the toggle animation completes. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-duration-complete)

```
function refreshdata()
  $('.overlayloading').toggle("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    fetchData();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
function refreshdata() {
  $('.overlayloading').toggle(true);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(fetchData);
}
```

to make sure the display toggle actually takes full effect in the view before invoking `fetchData`.